# SQL Server stored procedure return null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the question about creating a stored procedure by some value, I write procedure but then value include dot so he return nothing.

There is my code:

```
create procedure GetUserInformationByUsername 
    @username nvarchar(50) 
as
    select 
        ISNULL(u.FirstName, 'Unknown') as [First Name], 
        ISNULL(u.LastName,'Unknown') as [Last Name],
        ISNULL(u.Language,'Unknown') as [speak Language],
        ISNULL(c.CountryName,'Unknown') as [Country Name]  
    from 
        UsersProfile u 
    join 
        Countries c on u.CountryID = c.CountryID
    where 
        u.UserName = @username
go
```

`@username` is "alex.a" what I want to find,

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you mean zero record?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that the proc brings back an empty result set. If so, there are two things that could be happening.

1. You don't have a user with a UserName = "alex.a"
2. Your join against the Countries table doesn't find a matching CountryID

I'm guessing it's #2.